# Pointwise convergence of Fourier transform in L2

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, pointwise-convergence

I am wondering the following problem: given $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in L^2(R)$, with $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$, how does $\hat{f_n}$ converge to $\hat{f}$? The $L^2$ convergence is straightforward. Also I am wondering the case of $f_n=\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}f$, which yields the following 2 problems:

1. Is it true that for any $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f\in L^2(R)$ with $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$, we have $\hat{f_n}\to \hat{f}$ a.e. (as $n\to\infty$)? If not, what's the counterexample, and what conditions should $f$ and $f_n$ satisfy?
2. Is it true that for any $f\in L^2(R)$, $\mathcal{F}[\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}f](k)\to\mathcal{F}[f](k)$ a.e. (as $n\to\infty$)? If not, what's the counterexample, and what conditions should $f$ satisfy?

Comment: Plancherel answers 2. in the affirmative.

Comment: Can you provide some details? Plancherel only tells us some inner product things so I'm not sure how to get pointwise convergence.

Comment: The answer to 2 is affirmative, but this is nontrivial: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Plancherel transform is unitary, hence for both 1 & 2, the transforms converge in $L^2$ and hence pointwise ae. for some subsequence.

For 1, this is the best we can do without additional assumptions. To see this, let $\hat{f_n}$ be the sequence of indicator functions of sets of the form $[{k \over m}, {k+1 \over m})$, with $k=0,...,m=1$, and let $f_n$ be the inverse Plancherel transform of $\hat{f_n}$. It is straightforward to see that $\hat{f_n} \to 0$ in $L^2$ and so $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$. However, $\hat{f_n}(\omega)$ converges nowhere (pointwise).

For 2, let $f_n = f \cdot 1_{[-n,n]}$ and note that $\hat{ \hat{f_n} }(x) = f_n(-x)$ and similarly for $f$. Applying  [Carleson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=Carleson%27s%20theorem%20is%20a%20fundamental,by%20Lennart%20Carleson%20(1966).) (also [here](https://mat.uab.cat/pubmat/articles/view_doi/10.5565/PUBLMAT_48204_01) under article) and taking care of minus signs yields the desired result.